# Chart Production - chart series, etc

Tags: chart, autocad-map, hydrography

We do subsea surveys - seabed mapping etc. What software do you use to produce charts? I am especially interested in producing chart series.

It would be interesting to hear how you guys produce charts...

Answer (score 3):

HYPACK is a good one (users familiar with ArcMap or Adobe Illustrator would be at home)

[image: HYPACK]

http://www.hypack.com/new/Sales/Products/HYPACK/tabid/56/Default.aspx